# How to encrypt and decrypt access passwords in Django?

Tags: django, security, cryptography

My Django application needs a table to store credentials of different users to access external databases that store their information. There are security and technical reasons not to use the same database that Django uses. But during storage, I would like to encrypt the passwords before inserting to the persistance, and later a way to decrypt them in order to make use of them.

My first approach was to use make_password function, but I couldn't find a way to decrypt back the passwords.

Right now I'm testing django signals with a pre_save script that encrypts the password using cryptographi.fernet algorithm. And later, this is decrypted inside the view execution. For encryption and decryption, I'm saving the key in settings file (loaded from environment).

I would like to know if this is secure enough procedure to manage credentials to critical information of my users. Also if there is any way to get the password back when using make_password function.

Comment: FWIW, I’d create a custom model field which does the en-/decryption instead of a signal. Apart from that, since the server needs the key to do the crypting, it’s not super important where you store the key. Maybe having it in some external vault would be slightly more secure than a plain file; but generally an attacker managing to break into the server somehow will probably be able to do everything your server can anyway.

Comment: I think this pip package can be used - https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that your design has that you will need a master password in order to decrypt the passwords. Your problem is not trivial;  the recommendation to save passwords in databases is using hashes, but that solution does not work for you.

Another problem with the master key is it will be in memory, so, an attacker performing a memory dump could retrieve it and decrypt all passwords. So, maybe a zeroization after usage could be a solution for this. Now, use the solution more appropiate for your situation. The programming is not only one way...

In Django, a solution could be, a CharField in the model and in views implements the logic in order to encrypt/decrypt. Or use the pre_save script you mention. But regarding to your question if it is secure enough, it is depending of the information you are working on.